# Express-session creates a new session every page load

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, axios, express-session

I have a MERN web app with `express-session` which I'm trying to deploy to heroku. I configured the backend request using a proxy, by setting the proxy in the `package.json` file. It works as it should when both the front-end and back-end is running locally on `localhost`.

When I deploy the back-end to heroku, then after every browser refresh, express-session creates a new session/document in mongodb.

After a lot of debugging, it came out that setting `axios.defaults.baseURL` to the backend url was causing the issue. (I still don't know why.)

Apparently, setting the proxy in the `package.json` only works for development because when I deploy the app, the api's get called from the front-end url. So during development, when everything is running on localhost, and the proxy is set in `package.json`, then everything works well.

**The problem** is, when I set `axios.defaults.baseURL`. When I do that, then after every page reload, the session gets recreated.

What's the correct way to connect the front-end to the back-end?

**Session.js**

```
const session = require('express-session');
const MongoStore = require('connect-mongo')(session);
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

module.exports = function(app) {
    var sess = {
        secret: 'mySecret',
        cookie: { token: null },
        saveUninitialized: false,
        resave: true,
        store: new MongoStore({ mongooseConnection: mongoose.connection })
    };

    if (app.get('env') === 'production') {
        app.set('trust proxy', 1);
        sess.cookie.secure = true;
    }

    app.use(session(sess));
};
```

**Route.js**

```
module.exports = function(app) {
    app.use(cors());
    app.use(helmet());
    require('../middleware/session')(app);
    // Other routes...
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way `express-session` works, is that it saves a reference cookie locally, and when you send a request, whether it's get, post, put, or delete, that request sends that cookie ref along with the request to the backend. `Express-session` then sees that cookie ref, goes and gets the corresponding data from the data store so that you can use it in your application.

When setting `axios.defaults.baseURL`, the cookie doesn't get sent over from the local system to the backend. The way to send it, is by setting:

```
axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;
```

That makes sure the cookies get sent over. Once you set that, then you will have to set a specific `origin` with CORS, and you can't use `'*'`.